# How to increase perfomance for loop using c#

Tags: c#, ms-project

I compare task data from Microsoft project using a nested `for` loop. But since the project has many records (more than 1000), it is very slow.

**How do I improve the performance?**

```
for (int n = 1; n < thisProject.Tasks.Count; n++) 
{
    string abc = thisProject.Tasks[n].Name;
    string def = thisProject.Tasks[n].ResourceNames;
    for (int l = thisProject.Tasks.Count; l > n; l--) 
    {
        // MessageBox.Show(thisProject.Tasks[l].Name);
        if (abc == thisProject.Tasks[l].Name && def == thisProject.Tasks[l].ResourceNames) 
        {
            thisProject.Tasks[l].Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

As you notice, I am comparing the `Name` and `ResourceNames` on the individual `Task` and when I find a duplicate, I call `Task.Delete` to get rid of the duplicate

Comment: Please explain to us what the above code is doing.

Comment: Yah, with small project(<100 record).It good work :(

Comment: `works very very slowly(sometime it doesn't work).` What is the difference between `very slowly` and `it doesn't work`? Or are they the same thing?

Comment: it doesn't work its mean debug code and it running don't stop, i much stop by hand =.=

Comment: @gggg why don't you use Map ?

Comment: yah,MS project is microsoft project. What is Map??can u hint for me>??

Comment: @gggg Key-Value Pair, will be efficient for this
https://www.dotnetperls.com/map

Comment: @gggg My bad, I mean dictionary in C# (Map in Java)

Comment: You do know when deleting you should start at the top and work down right? not start at 1 because if you wanted to have the list 1,2,3,4,5 and you do a for list of 1 to count, you do 1 ok, 2 delete 4 delete 5 ....which sounds fine, but if it was 1,2,4,5,6,7,9 .. 4 would get missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hash check should be lot faster in this case then nested-looping i.e. O(n) vs O(n^2)

First, provide a equality comparer of your own

```
class TaskComparer : IEqualityComparer<Task> {
    public bool Equals(Task x, Task y) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name) && string.Equals(x.ResourceNames, y.ResourceNames);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Task task) {
        unchecked {
            return 
                ((task?.Name?.GetHashCode()         ?? 0) * 397) ^ 
                 (task?.ResourceNames?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't worry too much about the `GetHashCode` function implementation; this is just a broiler-plate code which composes a unique hash-code from its properties

Now you have this class for comparison and hashing, you can use the below code to remove your dupes

```
var set = new HashSet<Task>(new TaskComparer());
for (int i = thisProject.Tasks.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (!set.Add(thisProject.Tasks[i]))
        thisProject.Tasks[i].Delete();
}
```

As you notice, you are simply scanning all your elements, while storing them into a `HashSet`. This `HashSet` will check, based on our equality comparer, if the provided element is a duplicate or not.

Now, since you want to delete it, the detected dupes are deleted. You can modify this code to simply extract the `Unique` items instead of deleting the dupes, by reversing the condition to `if (set.Add(thisProject.Tasks[i]))` and processing within this `if`

Comment: During test program, I detect it does't delete last row in project(if last row is duplicate data).I try to change i <= thisproject .task.count? Can u explain help me??

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Project has a [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-sort-method-project) method which makes simple work of this problem. Sort the tasks by Name, Resource Names, and Unique ID and then loop through comparing adjacent tasks and delete duplicates. By using Unique ID as the third sort key you can be sure to delete the duplicate that was added later. Alternatively, you can use the task ID to remove tasks that are lower down in the schedule. Here's a VBA example of how to do this:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateTasks()

    Dim proj As Project
    Set proj = ActiveProject

    Application.Sort Key1:="Name", Ascending1:=True, Key2:="Resource Names", Ascending2:=True, Key3:="Unique ID", Ascending3:=True, Renumber:=False, Outline:=False
    Application.SelectAll
    Dim tsks As Tasks
    Set tsks = Application.ActiveSelection.Tasks

    Dim i As Integer
    Do While i < tsks.Count
        If tsks(i).Name = tsks(i + 1).Name And tsks(i).ResourceNames = tsks(i + 1).ResourceNames Then
            tsks(i + 1).Delete
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop

    Application.Sort Key1:="ID", Renumber:=False, Outline:=False
    Application.SelectBeginning

End Sub
```

Note: This question relates to algorithm, not syntax; VBA is easy to translate to c#.

Comment: Thanks Rachel@@Can i ask you a question? Now, I want to report actual work of each resource name(it mean report from MS project into excel).So, how to get data from Task Usage view?My code as above, i use Grant chant view :(

Comment: Use the [TimeScaleValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/timescalevalues-object-project) object to access work hours by period (e.g. by day).

Comment: Hi Rachel, I'm using your code but i have a problem for first column(ID). During debug,  Ascending(name) = true so ID is changes. I want to add new task into possible h+1 if not duplicate but i don't specify right value h :(

Comment: There is a `Renumber` argument in the `Sort` method; be sure to set that to False so the task IDs don't change.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused. My mean is first column in mpp file that number auto. I used task.ID, it don't change like you said. Thanks so much Rachel.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you all the items which are duplicates, so you can delete them from your original list.

```
thisProject.Tasks.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.ResourceNames}).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(g => g.Select(c => c));
```

Note that you probably do not want to remove all of them, only the duplicate versions, so be careful how you loop through this list.

Comment: Also, MoreLinq (https://code.google.com/archive/p/morelinq/) allows you to use `DistinctBy`. See more ways of doing this here --> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535374/DistinctBy-in-Linq-Find-Distinct-object-by-Propert

Comment: Thanks oerkelens@@

Answer (score 0):

A Linq way of getting distinct elements from your Tasks list :

```
public class Task
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string ResourceName {get;set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Task> Tasks = new List<Task>();
        Tasks.Add(new Task(){Name = "a",ResourceName = "ra"});
        Tasks.Add(new Task(){Name = "b",ResourceName = "rb"});
        Tasks.Add(new Task(){Name = "c",ResourceName = "rc"});
        Tasks.Add(new Task(){Name = "a",ResourceName = "ra"});
        Tasks.Add(new Task(){Name = "b",ResourceName = "rb"});
        Tasks.Add(new Task(){Name = "c",ResourceName = "rc"});

        Console.WriteLine("Initial List :");
        foreach(var t in Tasks){
            Console.WriteLine(t.Name);  
        }

        // Here comes the interesting part
        List<Task> Tasks2 = Tasks.GroupBy(x => new {x.Name, x.ResourceName})
                                 .Select(g => g.First()).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("Final List :");
        foreach(Task t in Tasks2){
            Console.WriteLine(t.Name);  
        }
    }
}
```

This selects every first elements having the same `Name` and `ResourceName`.

Run the example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OuATtc).